# Ranked Choice Voting

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program where it performs a series of ranked choice elections based on an input text file containing 3 test elections, each with 5 ballots of the voters' choices out of the 3 candidates running for election. Then it outputs the winning candidate for each election.

The problem is that for the first test election, the output for the winner appears as "Candidate #-1 wins." when it's suppose to be "Candidate #2 wins." based on the results from the first test election.

I tried changing the return value from '-1' to '2' before the int main(). It did output what I wanted, but I'm trying to avoid hard-coding. If anyone could give me hints on how to fix this any other way, I would appreciate it!

Text File(elections.txt):

```
15
1
2
3
3
2
1
2
1
3
1
2
3
2
3
1
15
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
2
1
3
15
3
2
1
3
2
1
3
1
2
1
2
3
1
3
2
```

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const char *FILENAME = "elections.txt";
const int MAXBALLOTS = 500;
const int NUM_CANDIDATES = 3;

int elect_candidate(int ballots[MAXBALLOTS][NUM_CANDIDATES],
                    int numBallots) {

        int tally[NUM_CANDIDATES + 1] = { 0 };
        double percentages[NUM_CANDIDATES + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < numBallots; i++) {

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_CANDIDATES; ++j) {
        if (ballots[i][j] > 0)
            break;
        }
        if (j < NUM_CANDIDATES) {
        int choice = ballots[i][j];
        tally[choice]++;
        }
    }
        int best = 1;
        int bestCount = 0;
        int worst = 1;
        cout << "Percentages for each candidate: " << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i < NUM_CANDIDATES + 1; i++) {
            percentages[i] = (double)tally[i] / numBallots;
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
            cout << "#" << i << ": " << percentages[i];
            cout << endl;

        if (tally[i] > tally[best]) {
        best = i;
        bestCount = 1;
        } else if (tally[i] == tally[best]) {
        ++bestCount;
        } else if (tally[i] < tally[worst]) {
        worst = i;
        }
    }
    if (best == worst) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (2 * tally[best] > numBallots) {
        return best;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numBallots; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CANDIDATES; ++j) {
            if (tally[ballots[i][j]] == tally[worst]) {
            ballots[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream f(FILENAME);
    string tmp;
    int nLines;
    int numBallots = 0;

    int ballots[MAXBALLOTS][NUM_CANDIDATES];

    cout << "********************" << endl;
    cout << "C++ Election of 2020" << endl;
    cout << "********************" << endl;

    // While we are not at end-of-file
    while (getline(f, tmp)) {
        // Read the number of lines for this election
        nLines = atoi(tmp.c_str());
        // Read in each ballot
        for (int i = 0; i < nLines; i += 3) {
            // Read in a single ballot (3 lines each)
            cout << "Read ballot: ";
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CANDIDATES; j++) {
                getline(f, tmp);
                ballots[numBallots][j] = atoi(tmp.c_str());
                cout << " " << ballots[numBallots][j];
            }
            numBallots++;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Read " << numBallots << " ballots..." << endl;
        cout << endl;

        int winner = -1;

        // Run the election
        winner = elect_candidate(ballots, numBallots);
        cout << "********************" << endl;
        cout << "Candidate #" << winner << " wins." << endl;
        cout << "********************" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        numBallots = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Output:

```
********************
C++ Election of 2020
********************
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  3 2 1
Read ballot:  2 1 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  2 3 1
Read 5 ballots...

Percentages for each candidate:
#1: 0.40
#2: 0.40
#3: 0.20
********************
Candidate #-1 wins.
********************

Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  2 1 3
Read 5 ballots...

Percentages for each candidate:
#1: 0.80
#2: 0.20
#3: 0.00
********************
Candidate #1 wins.
********************

Read ballot:  3 2 1
Read ballot:  3 2 1
Read ballot:  3 1 2
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 3 2
Read 5 ballots...

Percentages for each candidate:
#1: 0.40
#2: 0.00
#3: 0.60
********************
Candidate #3 wins.
********************
```

Expected Output:

```
********************
C++ Election of 2020
********************
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  3 2 1
Read ballot:  2 1 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  2 3 1
Read 5 ballots...

Percentages for each candidate:
#1: 0.40
#2: 0.40
#3: 0.20
********************
Candidate #2 wins.
********************

Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  2 1 3
Read 5 ballots...

Percentages for each candidate:
#1: 0.80
#2: 0.20
#3: 0.00
********************
Candidate #1 wins.
********************

Read ballot:  3 2 1
Read ballot:  3 2 1
Read ballot:  3 1 2
Read ballot:  1 2 3
Read ballot:  1 3 2
Read 5 ballots...

Percentages for each candidate:
#1: 0.40
#2: 0.00
#3: 0.60
********************
Candidate #3 wins.
********************
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger yet? Btw, you should do some more divide and conquer. Identify parts of your code that can be named and make them functions or methods of some class. If you do that, after each call of one of the parts, you can look at the current variables (by debugger or by print) and verify it, finding out which part works wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a learning exercise that you want to solve on your own, and I have a policy of not writing code for those.

However, if I could make a suggestion: try representing each ballot as a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of candidates, stored in increasing order of preference, that is, last choice, next-to-last, ..., second choice, first choice. Then store the ballots in a [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) whose keys are the candidate each ballot currently has selected. (**Edit:** A `std::unordered_multimap` is even better.) You might insert [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) that own the ballot data, or just move the vector around and save yourself the extra level of indirection. For example:

```
using Candidate = int;
// A ranking of candidates in order of last-place to first-place:
using Ballot = std::vector<Candidate>;
// A collection of ballots, each keyed to the highest-ranking candidates
// on the ballot who is still alive:
using BallotBox = std::unordered_multimap< Candidate, Ballot >;
```

So, if I prefer Alice to Bob and Bob to Carol, my ballot would be stored in the `BallotBox`, inside a `BallotNode` whose key is the `Candidate` `alice`, my first choice, and that references the ballot data `{carol, bob, alice}`.  If Alice is eliminated, the algorithm reduces the length of the `Ballot` vector so that it now becomes `{carol, bob}`, and updates the `BallotNode` key to `bob`, my new choice.

You can insert each ballot into the `BallotBox` (a multimap container) with [`ballot_box.emplace(BallotNode( candidate, ballot ))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/emplace). You would then insert each ballot into the `BallotBox` within your input loop, and pass ownership of the `BallotBox` itself to the function that counts votes, to be consumed.

Counting the number of votes for a candidate is the member function [`ballot_box.count(that_jerk)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/count).  The nodes representing ballots for a given candidate are those in the range [`ballot_box.equal_range(loser)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range).

Each `Ballot` is a vector whose most-preferred choices are stored later. Therefore, finding its next choice is simply decrementing the length of the vector. This is a trivial constant-time operation. If you reverse-iterate until you find a candidate who’s still in the race, you maintain the invariant that the last element of any ballot is its current most-preferred choice.

You can then reassign all ballots for each eliminated candidate by [iterating over them](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), [extracting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/extract) each `BallotNode` that matches the key, finding the lesser evil on the `Ballot` it contains, making a new node whose key is the next candidate on the ballot, and inserting or emplacing the new node back into the multimap.

You must create a new node to insert, and cannot safely re-use the one you extracted, because you need to update its key, which is constant.  You can, however, move rather than copy its ballot data.

You do not explain the details of the ranked-choice algorithm, and in particular, whether there are any tiebreakers.  For example, if the first tiebreaker is the number of first-place votes, the second tiebreaker is the number of second-place votes, and so on, you would need to make a copy of the tiebreaker data before you start to modify the data in your ballot box.

Finally, since ties are possible, consider defining a Result type that can return one or more winners, for example, a `std::set<Candidate>`.

### Okay, Some Code

I waited a few days, and I changed the input format enough that you couldn’t just turn this in.  But it was an interesting enough problem that I solved one much like it myself, and learned a few things.  The trickiest bug I got was that extracting nodes from the ballot box invalidated iterators into it, so I had to change how I pulled out the votes for the losing candidate.

I then went back and changed the data structures `std::multimap` and `std::set` (which are intended to use trees) with `std::unordered_multimap` and `std::unordered_set` (which are intended to use hash tables).  Not only does this speed up access, but if you know in advance the input size, you can use `.reserve()` to do your allocation up-front.

The final result doesn’t have any manual memory management, make any deep copies, write any new classes, or even create any smart pointers.  It just moves STL containers around.

```
// This program requires C++17 or higher.

/* For the purposes of this exercise, data is read from standard input.
 * Data consists of zero or more election tallies, terminated by newlines.
 * The input encoding is UTF-8.  Lines beginning with # are comments, and
 * ignored.  Parsing and input-checking are minimal.
 *
 * Each election tally consists of:
 * - One line consisting of the number of ballots, N
 * - N ballots, each on its own line, consisting of space-separated integers,
 *   each identifying a candidate.  Higher-ranked candidates appear before
 *   lower-ranked ones on each ballot, no candidate may appear more than
 *   once on the same ballot, and a candidate must be the first choice of at
 *   least one voter to win.
 *
 * The expected output is, for each election tally:
 * The ID of the inning candidates (or a space-separated list of all candid=
 * ates tied for first place) followed by a newline.
 *
 * If more than one candidate is tied for last place, which last-place can-
 * didate is eliminated is arbitrary.  This could lead to an ambifuous result.
 * The algorithm doesn’t do tiebreakers (such as most first-place votes).
 */

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using Candidate = int;
// A ranking of candidates in order of last-place to first-place:
using Ballot = std::vector<Candidate>;
// A collection of ballots, each keyed to the highest-ranking candidates
// on the ballot who is still alive:
using BallotBox = std::unordered_multimap< Candidate, Ballot >;
using CandidateSet = std::unordered_set<Candidate>;

// Magic constant to make turn off lenght-checking:
constexpr auto huge_size = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();

template <class It>
  std::ostream& print_list( std::ostream& out,
                            const It& begin,
                            const It& end )
/* Prints the elements in range to the provided stream, separated by spaces.
 * The type It must be a forward iterator.  Utility function intended to be
 * called by operator<< overloads.
 */
{
  if (begin != end) {
    out << *begin;

    It it = begin;
    ++it;

    while ( it != end )
      out << ' ' << *it++;
  }

  return out;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const CandidateSet& x )
{
  return print_list( out, x.cbegin(), x.cend() );
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const Ballot& x )
{
  return print_list( out, x.cbegin(), x.cend() );
}

CandidateSet get_unique_keys( const BallotBox& x ) noexcept
/* Generates the set of keys in x.
 */
{
  CandidateSet results;

  if (!x.empty()) {
    auto it = x.cbegin();
    const Candidate* previous = &it->first;
    results.emplace(*previous);
    ++it;

    while (it != x.cend()) {
      if (it->first != *previous) {
        previous = &it->first;
        results.emplace(*previous);
      }
      ++it;
    } // end while
  } // end if

  return results; // Guaranteed copy elision.
}

BallotBox collect_ballots( std::istream& in = cin )
/* Creates the first round of the next election in the input stream, or
 * else throws a std::runtime_error.
 */
{
  unsigned n_votes;

  in >> n_votes;

  if (!in)
    throw std::runtime_error("Expected: number of votes.");

  if ( in.peek() == '\n' )
    in.get();
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("Expected: newline.");

  BallotBox ballot_box;
  ballot_box.reserve(n_votes);

  while (n_votes--) {
    while( in.peek() == '#' )
      in.ignore( huge_size, '\n');

    Ballot ballot;
    do {
      Candidate c;
      in >> c;

      if (!in)
        throw std::runtime_error("Expected: Candidate ID.");

      ballot.push_back(c);
    } while ( in.get() == ' ' );
    // The above never checks which non-space character it consumed, but it
    // should have been a newline.

    // For convenience, we inserted elements in the reverse order that our
    // algorithm needs.  Reversing is faster than front-insertions.
    std::reverse( ballot.begin(), ballot.end() );

    // Now we need to insert a node keyed to the first choice into the
    // BallotBox (multimap).
    const Candidate kodos = ballot.back();
    ballot_box.emplace( kodos, std::move(ballot) );
  }

  while (in && !in.eof() && in.peek() == '\n')
    in.get(); // Chomp trailing newlines.

  return ballot_box; // Guaranteed copy elision.
}

CandidateSet count_ballots( BallotBox&& ballot_box )
/* Consumes the initial state of the election and returns the Results of the
 * election.
 */
{
  using Tally = BallotBox::size_type;
  constexpr Tally votes_for_Stalin =
    std::numeric_limits<Tally>::max();
  constexpr Candidate noman = -1;

  CandidateSet candidates = get_unique_keys(ballot_box);
  Tally most_votes = 0;
  Tally fewest_votes = votes_for_Stalin;
  Candidate loser = noman;
  Candidate winner = noman;

  for ( const Candidate i : candidates ) {
    const Tally votes = ballot_box.count(i);

    if (votes > most_votes) {
      most_votes = votes;
      winner = i;
    }

    if (votes < fewest_votes) {
      fewest_votes = votes;
      loser = i;
    }
  } // end for

  while ( most_votes < (ballot_box.size()/2U + 1U) &&
          most_votes > fewest_votes &&
          !candidates.empty() && 
          !ballot_box.empty() ) {

    std::vector<Ballot> changed_votes;
    changed_votes.reserve(fewest_votes);
    candidates.erase(loser);

    while ( auto handle = ballot_box.extract(loser) ) {
      Ballot& ballot = handle.mapped();

      do {
        ballot.pop_back();
      } while ( candidates.find(ballot.back()) == candidates.end() );

     if (!ballot.empty()) {
        changed_votes.emplace_back(std::move(ballot));
      }
    } // end while

    for ( Ballot& b : changed_votes ) {
      assert(!b.empty());
      const Candidate new_key = b.back();
      ballot_box.emplace( std::move(new_key), std::move(b) );
    }

    most_votes = 0;
    fewest_votes = votes_for_Stalin;
    loser = noman;
    winner = noman;

    for ( const Candidate i : candidates ) {
      const auto votes = ballot_box.count(i);

      if (votes > most_votes) {
        most_votes = votes;
        winner = i;
      }

      if (votes < fewest_votes) {
        fewest_votes = votes;
        loser = i;
      } // end if
    } // end for
  } // end while

  if ( most_votes > fewest_votes ) {
   /* If this branch is reached, the while loop did not fail because all the
    * remaining candidates were tied: one candidate got more votes than
    * another.  Nor did it terminate because either the set of remaining can-
    * didates or the container of votes were empty.  Therefore, the loop
    * terminated for the only other possible reason: one candidate has won
    * a majority.
    */
    candidates.clear();
    candidates.insert(winner);
  }

  return candidates; // Guaranteed copy elision.
}

int main()
{
  try {
    while( cin && !cin.eof() ) {
      const auto next = cin.peek();

      if ( next == '#' || next == '\n' )
        cin.ignore( huge_size, '\n');
      else {
        cout << count_ballots(collect_ballots()) << endl;
      } // end if
    } // end while

    if (cin.fail())
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read from standard input.");

  } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
     cout.flush();
     cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some testcases. (A newline at the end is not optional.)

```
# Test data for rankedchoice.cpp
# Expected output: 4
8
1 4 3 2
2 4 3 1
2 1 4 3
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 4
3 1 4 2
4 2 3 1
4 1 3 4

# Expected output: 4
8
4 1 3 4
4 2 3 1
3 2 1 4
3 1 2 4
2 4 3 1
2 1 4 3
1 4 3 2
3 1 4 2

# Expected output: 1
1
1 2

# Expected output: 1
1
1

# Expected output: 2
3
1 2
2 1
2

# Expected output: 1 2
2
1 2
2 1

# Expected output: 1 3
6
1 2
1 3
1
3 2
3 1
2 3

# Expected output: 1
# Because there are no first-place votes for 4, it should be eliminated,
# and the 3 4 1 2 ballots should put 1 over the top on the second ballot.
9
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
2 1 3 4
2 4 1 3
2 4 1 4
2 4 1 3
3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2

# Expected Output: 3
5
1 2 3
2 1 3
3 1 2
3 2 1
3

# Expected Output: 3
5
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `elect_candidate`, you have an `else` statement that does a bunch of useless work, because you never make use of it after doing it.  You should make a determination of a winner within that `else` body and return it.  Since you're not doing that, the `return -1` at the end of the function gets executed.